# Override !important with javascript/jQuery for animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to animate the background-position-x, but it has a `background-position: 0 0 !important;` on it in the css that I can't remove. Is there any way around it with javascript? I see that my jQuery code is doing it's work, it's just that the css value is overriding it.

I've googled, but it seems like I can't add `!important` to my animate function.

//Edit. Or even better if I can do this with pure css??

Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.section').animate({
    'background-position-x': '100%'
  }, 100000, 'linear');
});
```

//Edit 2. This actually seem to work:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  to {
    background-position: 100% 0px; } 
}

.section {
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 200s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 200s linear infinite;
  animation: animatedBackground 200s linear infinite; 
}
```

//Edit 3. Well actually, it looks like FF still overrides with the !important and adding !important inside the keyframes block doesn't have any effect. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to do it with CSS and transitions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition - then you would apply a class to make the transition happen.

Comment: If you have a working answer, it is allowed to answer your own question .

Comment: Well actually, it looks like FF still overrides with the `!important` and adding `!important` inside the keyframes block doesn't have any effect. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me. I also added a 50% to make it bounce!

```
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0px; } 

    to {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }
}

.section {
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 200s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 200s ease infinite;
  animation: animatedBackground 200s ease infinite; 
}
```

Comment: @escapeVelocity In 2 days yes! However I added a comment above. Still some things that needs to be figured out!